# mvn test command shows build failure with error code 9667

Tags: maven, selenium

My 'maven test' command working perfectly and shows as Build success in eclipse. But when I try the same in my cmd prompt it shows build failure with error code 9667 and google not shown any reason for that. Anyone help me to get out of it.

```
D:\eclipse-workspace\SimpleMavenProj>mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building DemoMavenProj 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:3.2.4 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.313 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-04T16:53:53+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/77M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] 9667
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

My pom.xml file is mentioned below. I am not seen any problems in my pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>careData</groupId>
  <artifactId>SimpleMavenProj</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>DemoMavenProj</name>
  <description>DemoMavenProj</description>
    <properties>
        <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/smokesuite.xml</suiteXmlFile> 
        <mavenVersion>4.0.0</mavenVersion>
        <selenium.version>3.4.0</selenium.version>
        <testng.version>6.9.9</testng.version>
        <POI.version>3.7</POI.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies> 
         <!-- Selenium Dependency -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
         </dependency> 
         <!-- TestNG Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- POI Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${POI.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Log4j Dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But java_home mentioned in mvn -version and actual java_home are different. Read the below code. If it is the problem area how can i change it.

```
D:\eclipse-workspace\SimpleMavenProj>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-04T01:09:06+05:30)
Maven home: D:\eclipse-workspace\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

D:\eclipse-workspace\SimpleMavenProj>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
```

Comment: it seems like the dependencies you have added for the jar files are invalid.

Comment: `mvn --version` and `echo %JAVA_HOME%`. My best guess is that your Eclipse and CMD are both using different java versions and your CMD might be using 1.6 or something

Comment: No tarun. Both are using 1.8.0_131

Comment: No tarun. Both are using 1.8.0_131 but in mvn java home shown as  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre and actual java home is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131. If it is the problem how to solve it

Comment: @Kanagaraj - I dont think there's any problem with the Java Home that's being displayed by the `mvn -version` command. Have you tried triggering your `mvn clean test` with a `-e` (or) `-X` to see what is triggering that error code ? I copied your pom file, and its fine. `mvn clean test` seems to run just fine (I had to just get rid of the suite file reference in your pom)